# Is learning and cumulative reward a good metrics to evaluate a RL model?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

i am new to reinforcement learning.

I have a problem here that i am using DQN on. I have plotted a cumulative reward curve while learning and taking actions. After 100 episodes and it shows a lot of fluctuations that does not show me whether it has learnt anything.

However, instead of using learning and cumulative reward, I put the model through the whole simulation without learning method after each episode and it shows me that the model is actually learning well. This extended the program runtime by quite a bit.

In addition, i have to extract the best model along the way because the final model seems to be performing badly at times.

Any advice or explanation for this?

Comment: It is very difficult to answer without knowing the problem you are trying to solve, what is the network you are using and other implementation details

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the average mean return it's usually a good metric to know if the agent is improving or not.

If you're using [tf_agent](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents) you can do something like this :

```
...
checkpoint_dir = os.path.join('./', 'checkpoint')
train_checkpointer = common.Checkpointer(
    ckpt_dir=checkpoint_dir,
    max_to_keep=1,
    agent=agent,
    policy=agent.policy,
    replay_buffer=replay_buffer,
    global_step=train_step
)

policy_dir = os.path.join('./', 'policy')
tf_policy_saver = policy_saver.PolicySaver(agent.policy)


def train_agent(n_iterations):
    best_AverageReturn = 0
    time_step = None
    policy_state = agent.collect_policy.get_initial_state(tf_env.batch_size)
    iterator = iter(dataset)
    for iteration in range(n_iterations):
        time_step, policy_state = collect_driver.run(time_step, policy_state)
        trajectories, buffer_info = next(iterator)
        train_loss = agent.train(trajectories)
        if iteration % 10 == 0:
            print("\r{} loss:{:.5f}".format(iteration, train_loss.loss.numpy()), end="")
            
        if iteration % 1000 == 0 and averageReturnMetric.result() > best_AverageReturn:
            best_AverageReturn = averageReturnMetric.result()
            train_checkpointer.save(train_step)
            tf_policy_saver.save(policy_dir)
```

After 1000 steps the train function evaluates the average return and create a checkpoint if there are any improvements

Comment: that will work. I realise that the performace of my agent can deprove towards the end(even if i run for a long time). So what i do is that i retest it individually through the full simulation and take the best model. Is this the right approach?

Comment: I don't know how your agent is implemented but I think what you need is to implement a checkpoint system that saves the model each time the average mean improves. So even if the agent start forgetting what it has learned, you could load back the best model